# Py2exe bundling files into a single exe

Tags: python, windows, exe, py2exe

I'm having some trouble getting Py2exe to bundle all the files into a single .exe. It works
fine for me when I don't bundle them together. So this is the `setup.py` script I use when I'm not bundling them together, and it always works:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(console=['test.py'])
```

So I wanted to bundle all the files into a single executable, so I used this `setup.py` script for that, and this is the one that doesn't work:

```
from distutils.core import setup
# I took this off the Internet
import py2exe, sys, os
sys.argv.append('py2exe')
setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1}},
    windows = [{'script': "test.py"}],
    zipfile = None,
)
```

When I run this script, a dist directory is created with the test.exe file. If I execute it
by typing "test.exe" this error message pops up:

```
See the logfile 'c:\Python26\dist\test.ext.log' for details
```

And this is the contents of that logfile:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

So does anyone know how I can do this? I just want to bundle all the files Py2exe generates
with `test.py` into a single executable. I know it can do this. Or are there any other ways in which this can be done?

Comment: I would highly recommend [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/)

Answer (score 0):

just from the errorlog message, could you try again after assuring the last line of test.py ends with a carriage return? (press enter after the last line in test.py and save again)

Comment: Okay I've done that. I've confirmed that the test.py script works correctly. Same error message occurs so I don't know what to do.